# DropDownListFor population problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  public int SomeClassID { get; set; }
  ...
}

public class AnotherClass
{
  public int AnotherClassID { get; set; }
  public int AnotherClassText { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel that contains the following:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public SomeClass { get; set; }
  public List<AnotherClass> { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Strongly-Typed View of type `MyViewModel`.  I want to use `DropDownListFor()` in order to have a list of `AnotherClass` (value = AnotherClassID, text = AnotherClassText) and have whatever the user selects be assigned to the `SomeClass.SomeClassID`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you could also use my AjaxDropdown helper so you would just have to send to the view the int SomeClassId and get back the new one, the dropdown is going to be filled via ajax in the view (http://awesome.codeplex.com) I have some demo projects in there where I show how I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int SomeClassID { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public int AnotherClassID { get; set; }
    public int AnotherClassText { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }
    public List<AnotherClass> AnotherClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            AnotherClasses = new[] 
            {
                new AnotherClass { AnotherClassID = 1, AnotherClassText = 1 },
                new AnotherClass { AnotherClassID = 2, AnotherClassText = 2 },
                new AnotherClass { AnotherClassID = 3, AnotherClassText = 3 },
            }.ToList()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO: 
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SomeClass.SomeClassID, 
    new SelectList(Model.AnotherClasses, "AnotherClassID", "AnotherClassText"))%>
```

Comment: it's correct but do you do it like this in your real projects ? the sending entities to the view, and using the selectlist(,,) inside the view

Comment: Yes, that's how I do it in real projects except that I use a repository to fetch the data instead of hardcoding it but that's obvious. I populate a view model in the controller and pass it to the view. In the view I use SelectList to create the dropdown and choose which properties from the view model to bind to. It is also possible to use directly SelectList as a property of the view model but personally I prefer keeping this logic in the view. It just seems easier when mapping between domain models and view models with AutoMapper to avoid SelectList but it works also like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to your ViewModel that gets and sets the `SomeClassID`, then make the dropdown like this:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeClassId, 
    m.OtherClasses.Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Text, value = o.ID})
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Issues with casting since SelectListItem.Value wants an int.

Comment: @Brian: So what's your ID property? Why can't you cast it?

Comment: m => m.SomeClassId is an int, are you suggesting I ToString() that?